# Keycloak access tokens invalid after Keycloak server restart

Tags: keycloak

We are using Keycloak 3.4.0 / Keycloak.js in our single page app. Keycloak stores its data within a MariaDB.

When I restart the Keycloak server (NOT MariaDB) and refresh my single page app I am redirected to the login page. I thougt that Keycloak stores all tokens within its database, shouldn't these tokens still be valid after a restart? Or is it expected that all sessions are logged out?

Do I have to use offline tokens to support this scenario?

> The offline token is valid even after a user logout or server restart.
>   https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.4/server_admin/index.html#_offline-access

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is written by [one of the members](https://github.com/stianst) of the Keycloak development team:

> The JPA user session provider was
>   dropped (performance was horrible so we deemed it unusable). The user
>   session persister is only used for offline sessions, they survive a server
>   restart.

So yes, it seems like they removed it because of performance related issues. Here you've got the [whole thread](http://keycloak-user.88327.x6.nabble.com/keycloak-user-Remember-me-doesn-t-work-after-keycloak-restart-td1004.html).