# How to persist infinispan Session after Keycloak docker restart

Tags: docker, session, jboss, keycloak, infinispan

I have a running keycloak 8's docker but whenever I restart it, all non-offline session disappears. Result, all users are being disconnected whenever I come to update keycloak.

#### Causes:

- I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203490/keycloak-access-tokens-invalid-after-keycloak-server-restart) here and understood why access token aren't persisted (mainly performance issue).

As solution I've wanted to use Clusters (as recommended [here](http://keycloak-user.88327.x6.nabble.com/keycloak-user-Remember-me-doesn-t-work-after-keycloak-restart-td1004.html)), and I understood, that the core part is only well managing Infinispan.

#### Ideas:

- I first wanted to store that infinispan outside docker container (in a volume), then search where does the JBoss saves Infinispan in a docker, but i didn't found anything.
- Secondly I thought about an SPI to manage user sessions externally, but it seems not to be the right solution, as infinispan does already a good Job.
- Setting up then a cluster, helped by [this article about Cross-Datacenter support in Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/2017/09/cross-datacenter-support-in-keycloak.html) and [this other one about Keycloak Cross Data Center Setup in AWS](https://www.keycloak.org/2018/01/keycloak-cross-data-center-setup-in-aws.html) seemed to be a good starting point, but I'm still actually using dockers and I not sure if it's a better idea for me to build docker images from those tutorials.

Any more Idea would be welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just yet I've tried using docker cluster a second time, but now using docker swarm with the info from [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/):

> The PING discovery protocol is used by default in udp stack (which is used by default in standalone-ha.xml). Since the Keycloak image runs in clustered mode by default, all you need to do is to run it:
>
> `docker run jboss/keycloak`
>
> If you run two instances of it locally, you will notice that they form a cluster.

I've deployed very simply 3 instances of keycloak in clustered mode with an external database (postgres) using docker stack and it worked well.

Simpler said, keycloak docker does already handle this use-case when using clusters.

For more about the cluster use-case, please refer to this tutorial about how to [setup Keycloak Cluster](https://www.keycloak.org/2019/04/keycloak-cluster-setup.html)

Comment: Thanks for info. But how did you turn on user sessions persistence? Postgres database not guaranteed that your sessions in infinispan will be alive after docker restart.

Comment: When you have one instance Keycloak running in the cluster, it won't be alive after restart. But if you have multiple instances, each will connect to the infinispan, maintaining user sessions. Keep in mind that if you restart one instance before the other is fully started, you'll still loose user sessions