# Validate token on keycloak server for every api call

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I have keycloak spring microservice and regular java spring service using keycloak adapter & keycloak-spring-boot-starter.
When keycloak issues a valid token and I pass it over to spring service the validation token is valid and everything works fine.

And if I restart the keycloak service and I pass the previously issued token again to the spring service the validation passes again. Why is that? I would like for spring to figure out that the token was issued by a previously existing keycloak instance and report an invalid token.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the token payload it has the following details 
[image]

So just by restarting the keycloak instance without changing anything will not make the token invalid, this would create a lot of issues.
There is one option, where if the instance itself is changed for example hostname, this will result in token validation to return **active:false**.

For example if I request the token with below URL

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

and validate it with this introspection url, the token will be shown as valid.

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect
```

But, if I just change the hostname to 127.0.0.1 in my introspection url, the token is not valid anymore

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect
```

So AFAIK, you might need to brew up some custom logic for this.

The other best option is to keep the access token lifespan very limited.

Answer (score 0):

According to this Post [keycloak-access-tokens-invalid-after-keycloak-server-restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203490/keycloak-access-tokens-invalid-after-keycloak-server-restart) Keycloak is already behaving like this.

Tokens can also be verifyed using the public key of Keycloak to verify the signature and e.g. the expiration date of the token to check if it is still valid. As far as I know, the spring boot adapter uses this approach which will not everytime connect to Keycloak and therefore can not recognize if Keycloak has restarted.

Maybe there is an option to force the check to connect to Keycloak everytime or you need to implement this at least partly by your own.